# Roots of integral of Airy function (matlab)

Tags: matlab

I want to solve the following equation

[image: $$int_{x}^\infty Ai(\eta) d\eta=0$$]

I am doing something wrong with the definition of the function but I still don't get it

```
function F=myairyint(x)

F=integral(@(x)airy,x,1000)

end

functi2=@(x) myairyint;
x0=-1:-1:-15;
fsolve(functi2,x0)
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: What is your Ai(eta)? How is it defined? You should define what Ai is at first then you can include it into integral.

Comment: it's the Airy function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your integral seems to have no roots in `[-15 -1]` and converges to zero. I have tested it via plotting:

```
x0 = linspace(-20,20);
airyint = arrayfun(@(x0) integral(@(n) airy(n), x0, inf), x0);
plot(x0, airyint);
```

[image]

I also tested it via `fzero()` such as:

```
f = @(x) integral(@(n) airy(n), x, inf);
fzero(f, 0)
```

Output is as expected:

```
ans =

    115.8524
```

But it seems like every real numbers for *x > 115.8524* will look like roots of this integral equation.

**Additional:**

`fzero()` is a function trying to find roots looking at the values of funtion between two dynamic intervals. If it catches minus and positive values, it is narrowing the interval to catch the root. But there is an error rate since you also can observe from this example. This equation will be zero only when x goes to infinity which means there is no real roots of this equation.

Comment: The root is allowed to be complex. However, when I initialize fsolve near one of these roots, it never finds them

Comment: @Hans it is because that `fsolve()` is defined to find real roots.

Comment: Yeah, you are absolutely right... I have tried to input a vector (for the real and imaginary parts)as the initial guess but it doesn't work either, do you have any idea?

Comment: @Hans Your question was related to a problem with the declaration of your integral function and MATLAB's `fsolve()` function. I guess the answer satisfies the asked question, and I truly did my best to help you about your existing question. Since you now have a defined function, and seeing that there is no real roots, I advice you to ask a new question about _how to find complex roots of non-polynomial functions_.